# Correcting timestamp script .. Quick Q

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm very new to scripts so I'm just trying to get this script working for my sheet.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment it seems it will enter a timestamp in column F if data is inserted into E. 
I'd like the time stamp to go into A; Instead of nextCell, what would correspond to column A?

Thanks and sorry for the newbie question!

**Updated**

Thanks! That worked great and helped with my understanding too : )

If I want this to apply to multiple sheets but not all.

I tried adding additional lines but it doesn't seem to have worked.. where have I gone wrong?

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sanshiro" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
    if( s.getName() == "Josh" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
      if( s.getName() == "Suil" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses the [offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)) method to get the cell to be updated:

> `offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)`
>
> Returns a new range that is offset from this range by the given number
>   of rows and columns (which can be negative). The new range will be the
>   same size as the original range.

So, if you want to write 4 columns to the left (column A) instead of one to the right (column F), just replace this line:

```
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
```

with:

```
var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'; //name of the sheet the script should work on 
var colToWatch = 5 // watches for edits made in col E
if (e.range.columnStart !== colToWatch || e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== sheetName) return;
e.range.offset(0, -4) //offset the currently edited cell by 0 rows, -4 columns 
    .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);
}
```

See if this works for you ?